# Grid Property Similar to Flex-Grow

Tags: css, css-grid

[I discovered a bug with Chrome version 75's implementation of flexbox.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533293/padding-prevents-element-from-rendering-in-chrome-v75) Hence I wanted to see if the issue persists with `grid`, but the test will only work if there is a `grid` property that is similar to `flex-grow` due to the current structure of my document.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  /* height is implicitly determined by font-size and padding */
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
footer {
  /* height is implicitly determined by font-size and padding */
}
```

Is there a similar `grid` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on `1fr` to fill the remaining space:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: red;
}

main {
  background: green;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:10px;
}

footer {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>this is a header</header>
<main>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean enim nulla, tincidunt at laoreet sed, sodales a arcu. Cras cursus diam eget diam venenatis egestas. Sed in massa pharetra, malesuada felis et, posuere nisl. Etiam eget mauris suscipit, consequat leo in, tincidunt lectus. Morbi pellentesque accumsan lectus sed finibus. Vivamus eros mi, eleifend vitae nibh id, vulputate posuere nulla. Integer dictum justo non nunc tincidunt, lacinia faucibus nisl vestibulum. Mauris luctus ultrices diam, at malesuada sem. Curabitur auctor, mauris in fermentum vestibulum, libero velit molestie leo, ut placerat velit ligula vel mauris. Integer tortor purus, sagittis vel libero sed, egestas vehicula velit. Mauris ullamcorper, arcu at facilisis vehicula, lectus lacus scelerisque felis, ut mattis dolor justo ac tellus.

Fusce porttitor turpis eget felis vestibulum viverra. Sed hendrerit nisl interdum tortor suscipit convallis. Donec aliquet massa sapien, ac congue lacus ullamcorper sed. Donec felis lectus, fermentum ut vestibulum sit amet, mattis ac ipsum. Etiam ut purus libero. Mauris maximus sem at ex posuere, at venenatis nisi sollicitudin. Vestibulum consequat sem risus, vitae sodales augue rutrum venenatis. Vivamus varius, lectus consequa
</main>
<footer>this is a footer</footer>
```

Comment: with flexbox, `header` always remains visible at the top of the page, whereas `footer` always remains visible at the bottom of the page, even when the content of `main` is too big for the remaining space. in other words, in a `grid` context, `main` seems to grow beyond the remaining space if there is enough or too much content, whereas in a `flex` context you can make it so that `main` only ever takes up the remaining space and itself becomes scrollable. does that make sense? im going to edit my question

Comment: it might have something to do with the implicit `heights`

Comment: @Anthony this is what I have done, no? check the update, I added some content and scroll

Comment: hmmm something in my code must be interfering with it or something. lemme check my code

Comment: ahhh you had `100vh` and not `100%`. this might break it on mobile. ill have to test, but youve answered my question nonetheless.

Comment: so the issue/bug with chrome v75 has something to do with flexbox specifically

Comment: @Anthony it can also work with `100%` but you have to also add 100% to `html`

Comment: thats the way i had it, `html, body { height: 100% }`, and it wasnt working that way. `main` grows beyond the remaining space when its set to `100%` locally on my machine for some reason.

Comment: @Anthony Ah, don't tell you aren't adding the Doctype at the top of your document?

Comment: what do u mean??? i just found out why it wasnt working with `100%`, it had something to do with some of the other styles i was applying to both `html, body {}`

Comment: @Anthony I meant this : `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Are you adding it to the top of your document?

Comment: nono def not lol was adding it in CSS. i believe the issue was i also had `html, body { display: grid; }` which was being applied to both of em

Comment: is it true that if i adjust styles via JS (i.e. `ele.style.top = n + 'px'`) the browser always re-renders the document, whereas if i simply add, remove, or toggle a class, the browser doesnt end up re-rendering?

Comment: @Anthony it doesn't matter how you change the value (either with JS or with CSS), the browser will always re-render on value changes

Comment: ok thanks. i watched [a recent conference talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l23fbEZ-jKE) the other day and if i remember correctly im pretty sure buddy said changing any styles via JS forces the WHOLE page to re-render, whereas if u change a style via CSS only parts of the document are re-rendered??

Comment: @Anthony probably there is more context on where he said this but from what I know there is no difference in change a property value either inline or with a class. I will watch the video when I get a chance to understand what he meant .. by the way here is a useful link: https://csstriggers.com/top

Comment: when u watch the video let me your thoughts on what he says regarding that!! thanks and thanks for the link too

Comment: hey buddy, i cant seem to find the question or my project wherein you offered the solution of styling elements via CSS VARs progressively with something like `nth-child`. do you know what im talking about? if so, could u point me to a reference somewhere? thanks <33

Comment: @BugWhisperer this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094769/8620333 ?